# Modify data and then insert, if it is exist already using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im using mysql and PHP.

I have a table  like

```
name    age     department
----    ---     ----------
aaa     10      1
bbb     25      1
ccc     25      2
```

When i **insert** the next row with **name=aaa**, i need it to be stored as **aaa(1)**.

When i **again insert a row** with **name=aaa**, i need it to be stored as **aaa(2)**.

Result should be like

```
name    age     department
----    ---     ----------
aaa     10      1
bbb     25      1
ccc     25      2
aaa(1)  36      2
aaa(2)  27      3
```

Is it possible to achive by mysql?

We can create any more columns also, if required.

Comment: Are you looking for a query to do this?

Comment: What language are you using to run the queries that insert the data? Can you post the insert related code?

Comment: yes it is possible. you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (name text,   age int,      department int);
insert into t1 values
("aaa", 10, 1),
("aaa(1)", 10, 1),
("bbb", 25, 1),
("ccc", 25, 2);

insert into t1 values(
  (select if(c, concat(name, "(", c, ')'), name) from 
    (select n.name, count(*) c from 
      (select @n:="aaa" name) n 
      join 
      (select name from t1) t 
      on t.name=n.name or t.name like concat(n.name, '(%')) ttt), 
  1, 1);

select * from t1
```

[**Demo on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9be48/1)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL it could be something like:

```
INSERT INTO `staff` SELECT concat('aaa',count(*)) as name, '36' as age,'2' as department FROM `staff` WHERE name='aaa'
```